Streamlit version 1.37 st.rerun() it doesn't work
I am using streamlit together with flask in the Python language. The problem is that as of version 1.37 of streamlit, st.experimental_rerun() no longer works, and only st.rerun() works, but when I use rerun, it gives me this error when it is executed:
RerunData(query_string='link...', is_fragment_scoped_rerun=True)

Does anyone know why? I have been looking in forums and the official guide, but I haven't found anything in this latest version since this version has only been out for a short time.
If anyone has had the same problem and solved it, I would appreciate it.
I have been looking in forums and the official guide, but I haven't found anything in this latest version, since this version has only been out for a short time. So I would like to solve that problem.

As far as I am aware, The issue you're facing seems to be a known regression. A temporary workaround might exist in community discussions, but there hasn't been an official fix yet. Keep an eye on Streamlit's GitHub and forums for updates. Maybe share it with them if you haven't already.
